# Unable to uninstall timedoctor from terminal

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I had timedoctor Lite installed on my Ubuntu 16.04 and I installed Timedoctro Pro here. 
Now I am unable to start any of them. I thought a clean re-installation would help and when I tried to uninstall the package by typing
`sudo apt-get purge timedoctor` it says unable to locate the package

Comment: How did you install them?

Comment: Followed this link http://support.timedoctor.com/support/solutions/articles/5000515285-how-to-install-time-doctor-in-linux-ubuntu-

Comment: See "For questions, comments or feedback regarding this topic, please send an email to support@timedoctor.com" so I suggest you send an email. In general ".run" files are attempts to install software written by people who do not know how to make a .deb . As timedoctor was not installed via apt, you can not remove it with apt (apt-get or software manager). try running setupxxx_timedoctor.run --help or --uninstall and hope they wrote an uninstall script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://un-install.info/128491/uninstall-time-doctor-for-linux-32bit.html

> Manually Uninstall Time Doctor for Linux 32bit 2.2.16 with Build-in
>   Uninstaller. Most computer programs are installed with its build-in
>   uninstaller that can also help uninstall the program.
>
> Click Start menu and move your mouse to All Programs. Find Search Time
>   Doctor for Linux 32bit 2.2.16 folder and click on its Uninstaller.
>   Follow its uninstaller and uninstall the program.

If you have problems contact time doctor : http://support.timedoctor.com/support/solutions/articles/5000515285-how-to-install-time-doctor-in-linux-ubuntu-

> For questions, comments or feedback regarding this topic, please send
>   an email to support@timedoctor.com

Answer (score 3):

If you've installed timedoctor using it's AppImage file,
you can follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680226/how-can-i-uninstall-an-appimage).

1. Delete the downloaded AppImage file
2. Delete "appimagekit-timedoctor-desktop.desktop" from *$HOME/.local/share/applications/.* to remove it's desktop entry.

   rm -rf ./appimagekit-timedoctor-desktop.desktop